# Why do C++ classes have two names?

Tags: c++, class

Simple question:
Why do classes in C++ have two names as in:

```
class name1 {
//variables and functions
} name2;
```

Comment: That's a variable declaration.

Answer (score 15):

`name2` is an object of type `name1`, just as if the code was

```
class name1 {
// variables and functions
};
name1 name2;
```

Comment: And that style is a legacy from C, almost never used in C++ for full-blown classes.

Answer (score 1):

We can create objects from a class in two way:

1. Writing name of object after class definition:

   ```
   class name1 {
       //variables and functions
   } name2;
   ```

   In this sample `name1` is the name of class, and `name2` is an oject of type `name1`.
2. Creating objects using variable definition notation:

   ```
   name1 name2;
   ```

   in this sample `name2` is an object that is created of type `name1`.